# New VGA cable (5 meter length) does not allow display setting 1920 *1080

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, vga

My Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop is having LED HDMI 1080 Full HD (ViewSonic) monitor. Which allows me to set display settings (maximum) 1920 * 1080 (16:9) if the VGA cable (monitor manufacturer supplied) attached.

When I replaced my VGA cable (monitor manufacturer supplied) with the New VGA cable (5 meter length), it does not allow me to set display 1920 * 1080 (16:9) but the blurred display comes to 1024 * 768.

How to get the original display settings of 1920 * 1080 with the new 5 meter length VGA cable?

Comment: 5 metres is AFAIK **far** too long.

Comment: Unless using **extremely** high quality cables and/or a low resolution (more resilient) and a high quality DAC (on the graphical card, generating the signal which goes onto the cable).  @OP: Analog signals and long cables are a bad combination.

Comment: For long connections and/or high resolutions, people in the know use quality coax cables and BNC connections: http://www.bluejeanscable.com/store/rgbhv/index.htm  Commercial-grade computer monitors (and CRT projectors) use five BNC connectors for RGBHV instead of a VGA HD15 connector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VGA cables use an analogue standard and so are suitable to signal loss due to length and quality factors.

The longer the cable, the less accurate the resulting output and so the maximum resolution will be limited.

A better option is to keep the signal digital, this will give you more opportunities. Does the desktop have any digital output? If it has DVI, you can get [DVI to HDMI converters](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=dvi%20to%20hdmi) for a reasonable price. If it only has VGA, it is possible to get a [converter to HDMI](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vga%20to%20hdmi) though, because of the processing required, its a little more expensive.

Obviously it would be better if the desktop has HDMI native output. You can get around [45-50m](http://www.bluejeanscable.com/articles/how-long-can-hdmi-run.htm) out of a top quality HMDI cable!!

Comment: +1 for 'does your desktop have a digital output'. If it has that will solve the OPs problem (after op gets an appropriate length digital cable).  OP: Other solutions are directly converting the analog VGA to digital (near the dekstop, before the signal degraded) or using a cheap add in graphical card with digital outs. The last is probably cheaper and results in better performance then using a converter.